# NestJS and mongo two way relation between post schema and user schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I am new to nest and mongo I am trying to do a relation where a user schema embeds a posts array with ids of posts and in the posts schema I want to embed the author which is a user schema with the user id but I keep running into this error in my console

```
Error: Cannot determine a type for the "Post.author" field (union/intersection/ambiguous type was used). Make sure your property is decorated with a "@Prop({ type: TYPE_HERE })" decorator.
```

this is my code

UserSchema

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import { Document } from "mongoose";

import { Post, PostSchema } from "src/posts/entities/post.entity";
export type UserDocument = User & Document;

@Schema()
export class User extends Document{
    
    @Prop({ index: true})
    name: string;
    
    @Prop([{ type: PostSchema}])
    posts: Post[]

}

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User)
```

PostSchema

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import { Document } from "mongoose";
import { User, UserSchema } from "src/users/entities/user.entity";

export type PostDocument = Post & Document;

@Schema()
export class Post extends Document{
    @Prop({index: true})
    title: string;
    @Prop({index:true})
    body: string;
    @Prop({type: UserSchema})
    author: User;
}

export const PostSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Post)
```

at the end what I am trying to achive in my database is this

users collection

```
{
    "_id" : "U1",
    "name":"user1",
    "posts": [
        {
            "_id": "P1",
            "title":"title 1",
            "body":"body 1"
        }
    ]
}
```

posts collection

```
{
    "_id" : "P1",
    "title":"title 1",
    "body":"body 1",
    "author": {
            "_id": "U1",
            "name":"user1",
    }
}
```

I am trying to embed doucments into each other with the ids so I can read fast and use the ids to update

Answer (score 0):

your user schema have a problem.

the way you define an array is wrong. use this one :

```
 @Prop({type: [PostSchema]})
 posts: Post[]
```

Comment: It did not work

Comment: can you share the error or any results?